# Date Object toLocaleString not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does the date and time NOT work with this syntax?

```
<script>

    Date.prototype.addHours = function (h) {
        this.setHours(this.getHours() + h);
        return this;
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#countdown").countdown({
            date: Date.addHours(1).toLocaleString(),
            format: "on"
            },

            function () {

                // callback function
            });
    });

</script>
```

But this DOES work perfectly fine:

```
<script>

    Date.prototype.addHours = function (h) {
        this.setHours(this.getHours() + h);
        return this;
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#countdown").countdown({
            date: "4/5/2014 12:13:16 PM",
            format: "on"
            },

            function () {

                // callback function
            });
    });

</script>
```

The change is on the date property. FYI

Comment: Because `Date` doesn't have an `addHours` method. Only *instances* of `Date` do. To learn more about prototypal inheritance, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date` is the constructor, and you need a `new` instance of it

```
$("#countdown").countdown({
    date: (new Date()).addHours(1).toLocaleString(),
    format: "on"
    },
```

Not sure if it matters, but note that not all users will get the same string back from `toLocaleString()`